# compiling DotNetNuke 06.02.05 throws exception in Globals.cs

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I just installed a fresh copy with source code of DotNetNuke 06.02.05.
I have compiled using VS 2010 but couldn't complete because of the following exception in globals.cs

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Source:

```
string strMessage = DataProvider.Instance().GetProviderPath();
```

i didn't change anything in the code, just opened the solution and compile.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `web.config` renamed `release.config` to `web.config`.